# jQuery get generated elements attributes FF vs IE problem

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, jquery-click-event

I have a click event on my select-tag (filterBA), and then the options are generated dynamicly.

```
$("#filterBA").click(function(event){
   var $tgt = $(event.target);

   if($tgt.is('option')){
        if($tgt.attr('id') != 0){
            sortRowsByBA($tgt.attr('id'));
        }else{
            appendOrReplaceRows("replace", getSortColumn(), getAscdesc());
        }
}
});
```

This works great... in firefox, but IE won't reconnize my $tgt as an option. I check by adding:

```
$("#filterBA").click(function(event){
    var $tgt = $(event.target);
    alert($tgt.is('option'));
    ...
```

And no matter what it returns false. But in FF it return true vi i hold my mouse down a selects one of the options. I don't get it, since i use the same approach when i have to select a div used in a custom select-list i created (in the same system), but when the click-event is on the  tag it won't work.

Anybody know what might be wrong?

btw. here is my function to generate the options:

```
function pupulateBA(){
$selectTag = $('#nav select').html('<option id="0">Select business area</div>');
$.ajax({
    url: "ajaxBAs.cgi",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsonData){
        for(var businessIndex in jsonData){
            $selectTag.append("<option id='"+jsonData[businessIndex].id+"'>"+jsonData[businessIndex].name+"</option>");
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Ajax error retriving business areas to frontpage.');
    }
});
```

}

**I found a solution:**

ofc im an idiot, since I forgot all about ":selected".. DOH! So here is my new event on my  tag:

```
$("#filterBA").change(function(){
    $('#filterBA option:selected').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

This works with both FF and IE on dynamically created options in a select-dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

From [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html).

> event.target - W3C/Netscape says: the target. No, says Microsoft, the srcElement.

Not positive how to work around it. Read the QuirksMode article though as it provides a function that may or may not do what you want it to do and also specifies a few other attributes that will hopefully work for you. Although I would hope that maybe jQuery had an abstracted version so that you don't have to worry about IE hacks.

Comment: Ahhh - your solution is so obvious. Missed the forest but for the trees.